# How to derive the despective-collective nouns from verbs?

Tags: verb, noun, nominalization

Is there a general rule to derive this sort of colloquial despective nouns:

> - schreiben  → das Geschreibe
> - rennen  →  das  Gerenne
> - schreien  → das Geschrei

I wanted to form that from *sing* but *Gesang* already exists, and it means of course something else, and *Gesänge* sounds like its plural. On the other hand *Sängerei* is my best option, but not having this *Ge-*, common to the others, I'm not sure at all if it would be understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

singen -> Gesinge 
is valid, exactly follows the pattern and style of your other examples while Gesang definitely lacks the despective aspect. So the rule appears to be: drop the -n, add the Ge-.

Comment: Would it work for, say, trinken: *Getrinke*?

Comment: Yup. Trying to think of counterexamples, none showed up so far.

Comment: Super, then I'll wait for others to upvote (also) your question before accepting it.

Comment: Found a semi-exception: essen does not become Geesse but Gegesse. Avoiding the awkward ee-collision. Heard Geesse in use, too, but it feels inferior to Gegesse. Besides that, have a good day :-)

Comment: Interessant. Dank deines Gegenbeispiels habe ich beim Googlen mehrere gefunden: *"Am frühen Morgen. das Gefrifire. das Grunge. das zur Kirche Gefahre. das Jagefage. das Getraue. das Gegeffe. das Getrinke und Getanze"* Wobei *f* halt *s* sein kann.

Comment: Gegesse? Nie gehört. Geesse? Nie gehört, aber klingt richtig.

Comment: Zu Ge(g)esse: https://books.google.de/books?id=3SonJRBfM5QC&lpg=PA107&dq=%22Gegesse%22&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=%22Gegesse%22&f=false

Comment: ...wobei für etwa "verstecken" würde vielleicht am besten "Versteckerei" und nicht "Geverstecke" passen.

Comment: @c.p. Sein kann? Your quote reads: "Am frühen Morgen, das Gefrisire (= Gefrisiere = hairdressing), das Geputze, das zur Kirche Gefahre, das Jagesage (= saying "I will" at the wedding ceremony), das Getraue, das Gegesse (= eating), das Getrinke und Getanze". As soon as you have German type, you have to diligently distinguish between "s" and "f" within a word.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla That's right. I didn't typed, though. Google did it from Fraktur; I just Ctr-C+Ctr-V-ed, since I couldn't identify some of the verbs. Whence "sein kann" because not all *f* there are *s*.

Comment: @c.p. Oh, you did it from Google automatic plain text which apparently isn't advisable at all because the transcription is everything but reliable, not to say awful...

Comment: Nicht schlecht, ein produktives Paradigma, um abwertende Bedeutung auszudrücken. Diese Sprache und ihr Prophet (dieses Forum) erstaunen mich immer wieder.

Comment: Veredomon, Danke fürs Gekommentiere ;) ...Ok, ohne Witz: Was würde man ohne die folgenden Worte machen: *das Getue, das Gerenne*, ... Die sind echt lieb. Nicht notwendiegerweise Abwertend, jedoch kann man ein Ding nicht *ein Schreiben* nennen, wenn es nur *Geschreibe* war.

Comment: Thanks for the link about Ge(g)esse,  @Carsten. Unfortunately, we apparently slashdotted the book behind it. Cannot access it anymore :(

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu, hmm, jedenfalls scheinen beide Formen zu existieren, auch wenn es schwer war, Belege zu finden.